# Vue packages version mismatch issue to run vue based application

Tags: vue.js, package, version, mismatch

I am facing an issue to run a vue based application and the error message is as below when tried to run -
Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.6.10
- vue-template-compiler@2.7.14

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

npm install worked properly.

Am I  missing anything?

Comment: I used ^2.6.11 for both but experienced the same thing.

Comment: Don't use loose version restriction when you need a strict one.

Comment: npm run serve provided the following error -  error  Parsing error: Cannot find module 'babel-eslint' and then installed "npm install -g babel-eslint" and working fine now.

Comment: This wasn't presented in the question, I don't see the link between these errors. It's unclear what's your case because the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , but if a project depends on a deps, it's supposed to be included in project deps.

Comment: Due to version change, again experiencing the following error- Vue packages version mismatch:
- vue@2.6.14 (\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.7.14 (\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)
                                                                                            Am I missing anything?

Comment: This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.           - error in command window

Comment: The comment above is still applicable, it's unknown what's your case. The error means that these lib versions are supposed to be matched

Comment: Yes, I used the same version but showing same error. Am I missing anything?